# SQLAlchemy many-to-many relationship on declarative tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following tables defined declaratively (very simplified version):

```
class Profile(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'profile'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
        name = Column(String(65), nullable = False)

        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name


class Question(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'question'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    description = Column(String(255), nullable = False)
    number = Column(Integer, nullable = False, unique = True)


    def __init__(self, description, number):
        self.description = description
        self.number = number



class Answer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'answer'

    profile_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('profile.id'), primary_key = True)
    question_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('question.id'), primary_key = True)
    value = Column(Integer, nullable = False)


    def __init__(self, profile_id, question_id, value):
        self.profile_id = profile_id
        self.question_id = question_id
        self.value = value
```

Profile is linked to Question via a many-to-many relationship. In the linking table (Answer) I need to store a value for the answer.

The documentation says I need to use an association object to do this but it's confusing me and I can't get it to work.

How do I define the many-to-many relationship for the Profile and Question tables using Answer as the intermediary table?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The documentation says I need to use
>   an association object to do this but
>   it's confusing me and I can't get it
>   to work.

That's right. And the Answer class is your association object as it maps to the association table 'answer'.

> How do I define the many-to-many
>   relationship for the Profile and
>   Question tables using Answer as the
>   intermediary table?

The code you've presented in your question is correct. It only needs additional information about relationships on the ORM level:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

...

class Profile(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'profile'

    ...

    answers = relationship("Answer", backref="profile")

    ...


class Question(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'question'

    ...

    answers = relationship("Answer", backref="question")

    ...
```

Also, **you shouldn't setup values for profile_id and question_id in your Answer's init function**, because it's the ORM that's responsible for setting them accordingly based on you assignments to relationship attributes of your objects.

You may be interested in reading **[documentation for declarative](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative.html)**, especially the part about **[configuring relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative.html#configuring-relationships)**. Reading about **[working with related objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#working-with-related-objects)** may be helpful as well.

Comment: Edited to fix broken links to documentation.

Comment: This doesn't look right. Your answer looks like it only links each side to the associative table via a many-to-one relationship. There is no mention of a many-to-many, i.e. the following usage implies many-to-many at the orm level: Profile.questions

Comment: @ZoranPavlovic Opening old wounds, but the problem with using `Answer` as secondary in a direct many to many relationship here is that `Answer` holds meta information, or columns that are not a part of the foreign keys between the 2 tables.